# Running nodejs with docker-compose doesn't work but work with docker run command

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a container with the Nodejs official docker image. All working with this "docker run" command below:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --name nodejs --volume ${PWD}/app:/usr/node/app --workdir /usr/node/app node:12 bash
```

But I would to use docker-compose so I trying this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nodejs:
    container_name: nodejs
    image: node:12
    working_dir: /usr/node/app
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/app:/usr/node/app
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

But when I run > `docker-compose up`

```
Creating network "node_default" with the default driver
Creating nodejs ... done
Attaching to nodejs
nodejs exited with code 0
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: It exited with code 0—that means no error. What were you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the docker run command, you are overwriting the CMD in the docker container and attach yourself directly to the shell of the container.

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --name nodejs --volume ${PWD}/app:/usr/node/app --workdir /usr/node/app node:12 bash
```

However, when using `docker-compose` or `Kubernetes`, things are not that simple. They will spin up the container and execute the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`. The container will then exit once those commands exit. In your case of `docker-compose`, it is executing [`docker-entrypoint.sh node`](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/12/alpine3.11/Dockerfile#L93-L95) which will exit immediately.

You can verify this by running `docker-compose ps` and see that the container status is `Exit 0`.

In case you want to keep your container running forever without exiting, you can update your `docker-compose` file to be like this

```
version: "3"

services:
  nodejs:
    container_name: nodejs
    image: node:12
    working_dir: /usr/node/app
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/app:/usr/node/app
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    entrypoint: bash
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        tail -f /dev/null
```

After that, you should run `docker-compose up -d` to run in the `detach` mode which leaves the container running in the background and verify that it is running with `docker-compose ps`.

In order to get inside your container you can run the command

```
docker exec -it nodejs bash
```

**NOTE:** If you run `docker-compose up`, it will seem like everything hang but in fact, you are seeing the `stdout` of that container which prints out nothing. `Ctrl+C` will get you out and stopping the container at the same time.